# How to create a shadow effect like sketch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, illustrator-effects

I want to know how to how to create a shadow in Adobe Illustrator, like this
[image: Example of shadow]

Comment: Hi Mr.Y, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: SHADOW Text - Illustrator Tutorial]

Hey man, check out the image - I show you step by step.

This is a slightly more complicated way that using the patterns panel, but it suits my workflow.

Hope this helps!